# Python 3 BS4 - Extract Data from <span> tags (Continued)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, tags

So I have HTML code that looks like this.

```html
<li data-ng-repeat="sector in data.sectors"> <a target="_self" data-ng-href="/stocks/quotes/-382G/components/A" href="/stocks/quotes/-382G/components/A"><span>SIC-3826 Laboratory Analytical Instruments</span></a> </li>
```

And I want to extract the information w/in the span tag. Unfortunately when I use the following code:

```
tags = soup.findAll("li",attrs={"data-ng-repeat":"sector in data.sectors"})
# tags = soup.find_all("a",attrs= {"target=","data-ng-href="})
# tags = soup.find_all("a")
for tag in tags:
print(tag.text)
```

the result is [[sector.description]]. 
What I want to extract is the information including "SIC-3826 Laboratory Analytical Instruments"

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have tried all sorts of alternatives yet I cannot get the information that I want.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is *[[sector.description]]*?

Comment: This looks like a classic case of dynamic contents being scraped.  If I had to guess, `[[sector.description]]` is a placeholder for the scripts to render the page with actual information.  You'll need a module that supports dynamic contents, try `selenium` or `requests-html`.  Unfortunately `bs4` just doesn't have the capability to read dynamically generated contents.

Comment: [[sector.description]] is what print(tag.text) responds rather than the text that appears w/in the <span> tag

Answer (score 0):

Yes all you need to do is:

```
x = """<li data-ng-repeat="sector in data.sectors"> <a target="_self" data-ng-href="/stocks/quotes/-382G/components/A" href="/stocks/quotes/-382G/components/A"><span>SIC-3826 Laboratory Analytical Instruments</span></a> </li>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
print(BeautifulSoup(x, "lxml").text)
```

Comment: What if `x` is a complete webpage? What happens then?

Comment: The issue is that I don't know what x is going to be before the page gets served. Either that or I may be misunderstanding your answer.